# Spring boot define preferred port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I write a spring boot application (which is configured throw a Spring Cloud Config Server).

This application has a small UI for information only. However, it should be possible to start this application multiple times so you can not set a fix port for this application (in the Config Server).

For this it is possible to set a random port (server.port=0) and you can start as many instances of this application as you want. A little issue is that if the user wants to access the UI he has to find out a “random port”.

So my question is: **Is it somehow possible to define a preferred Port (using Config Server) and only if this port is not available take a random port?**

Comment: What is the use case for using multiple instances of the same app? Are there different database connections or is there a difference between the instances?

Comment: Spring Cloud Eureka, Consul, Zookeeper are designed to handle this specific task.  I have only used Eureka.  In combination with Zuul the setup works very well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just configure it via command line system property `java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar app.jar`. Example is in [this section of Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cloud-deployment-heroku).
2. I bet also setting up environment variable `SERVER_PORT` may work.
3. I think also Spring Boot parameter should work: `java -jar app.jar --server.port=$PORT`